# Present modal in SwiftUI in full screen mode and prevent closing it

Tags: xcode, ipad, swiftui, modal-dialog, frame-size

I have a SplashView that acts as a starting view and opens the game screen in modals.

I just tried to open the game in an iPad instead of iPhone and the views look all weird.

When I switch to the game screen the screen is presented as a small screen in the middle and I can swipe it out to close it. Other screens from the logic are stacked on this screen.

How can I prevent the stacking and have all screen in full screen, similar to when I open it on an iPhone and prevent moving them by swiping?

[image: example of 2 stacked screens on the starting screen]

```
  .sheet(isPresented: $isPlayerDashboardModal) {
                if let playerState = PlayerViewModel.createNewGameData(name: playerName) {
                    let playerViewModel = PlayerViewModel(player: playerState)
                    CityView(viewModel: playerViewModel)
                }
            }.frame(minWidth: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.width, idealWidth: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.width, maxWidth: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.width, minHeight: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.height, idealHeight: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.height, maxHeight: DeviceTypes.ScreenSize.height, alignment: .center)
```

I set the frame to max already, but this does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Prevent from swiping down: use the `.interactiveDismissDisabled()` modifier on the outermost layer of the view. For the full screen cover, I believe that you are using `.sheet()`: that behaviour is the standard for iPad. To cover the background, you should put the welcome page on a `ZStack` and handle when it needs to appear.

Comment: Ok, thanks, .sheet is the issue. I found out that .sheet replacing with .fullScreenCover will help, will experiment further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace .sheet with .fullScreenCover to ensure that window is full screen and cannot be closed via pulling it down.
To hide the statusbar on iPad include: .statusBar(hidden: true) before the final view closure.